# Grab a value from one list when the value of another list equals a value

Tags: python, list, linked-list, return-value

I am extracting data and I am getting two separate lists. One list has the dates of when this test was done and the other list has if it's approved or not. For example

```
TestDate_lst = ['2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-04', '2022-03-24',
'2021-04-20', '2021-04-20']

Action_lst = ['Decline', 'Decline', 'Decline', 'Approve', 'Approve', 'Ignore', 'Decline']
```

What I am trying to do is that every time there is a Decline response in Action_lst you extract the date that it was declined.

The code that I have tried is:

```
DateTest = []

for i in TestDate_lst:
    for a in Action_lst:
        if a == "Decline":
           DateTest.append(i)
        else:
           pass
```

Output:

```
DateTest_lst = ['2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24',
'2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24',
'2022-03-24', '2022-03-04', '2022-03-04', '2022-03-04', '2022-03-04', '2022-03-24',
'2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2021-04-20', '2021-04-20', '2021-04-20',
'2021-04-20']
```

Expected:

```
DateTest_lst = ['2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2021-04-20']
```

I know the for loop is what is causing issues, and I thought about doing a dictionary to solve this problem but wasn't sure if this was the right path to take.

Comment: no double loop, zip the data and test status.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a double loop:

```
for i in range(len(TestDate_lst)):
    if Action_lst[i] == 'Decline':
        DateTest.append(TestDate_lst[i])

print(DateTest)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip).

```
TestDate_lst = ['2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-04', '2022-03-24',
'2021-04-20', '2021-04-20']

Action_lst = ['Decline', 'Decline', 'Decline', 'Approve', 'Approve', 'Ignore', 'Decline']

result = [t for t,a in zip(TestDate_lst, Action_lst) if a=='Decline']

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2021-04-20']
```

Check Performance:

```
TestDate_lst = ['2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-04', '2022-03-24','2021-04-20', '2021-04-20']*100_000
Action_lst = ['Decline', 'Decline', 'Decline', 'Approve', 'Approve', 'Ignore', 'Decline']*100_000
```

Benchmark on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)

```
%timeit [t for t,a in zip(TestDate_lst, Action_lst) if a=='Decline']
# 68.8 ms ± 18.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

second appeoach:

```
%%timeit
res = []
for i in range(len(TestDate_lst)):
    if Action_lst[i] == 'Decline':
        res.append(TestDate_lst[i])

# 108 ms ± 1.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Definitely both correct, but I'd say overengineered for such a simple task

Comment: @ChatterOne, Do you think `insert` is good? Or list comprehension and zip?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "insert is good", but my point is that your suggestions are: - a zip (which is a loop), that creates another data structure in memory, on which then you loop (again). - Importing a whole library like numpy to translate everything to another data structure, taking up even more memory, only so you can apply a mask. This task can be solved with a single loop and no extra memory other than what you need for the result.

Comment: please read [`np.asarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html). np.asarray don't create a copy of the list and don't use memory. only create a view of list as array.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you're importing a library that you might not need anywhere else. It's something that you or someone else will need to maintain, and add to the list of dependencies. No need for that.

Comment: @ChatterOne, Only give an alternative solution. You can check also read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html) for getting knowledge about memory.

Comment: @ChatterOne, Also check performance for `100_000` and you can seed seed 50% is faster.

Comment: We're in the realm of opinions now. I wouldn't underestimate the importance of maintanability / readability compared to speed. I'd say go with the simplest and more maintainable solution first, only try to make it faster if you actually need it to be faster, because it's not free, that has a cost, too. But I guess someone else might have a different opinion

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTest = []
for x,y in enumerate(TestDate_lst):
    if Action_lst[x] == 'Decline':
        DateTest.append(TestDate_lst[x])

print(DateTest)

#['2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2022-03-24', '2021-04-20']
```